# Program to fully tag any song automatically

Tags: linux, gratis, music, ubuntu, cross-platform

Is there any software which can recognize songs by the title (eg:Ron Pope-Home) and to tag it automatically?
I've got the songs in my PC,but they are untagged,you know...I download them from the internet and it gives me only the artist and the title,in general.I want a software which can tag all my songs automatically,something like this:I choose the files/folder->I click "Tag"/"Tag all" or such a button->The program loads the files->I got the singer/musician,the title,the album,the cover and the genre without doing more stuff manually.
And I think that some details would be useful for you to answer me:

- the program you suggest me is a freeware (not mandatory,but I would really appreciate to be FREE);
- is cross-platform or compatible with the major Linux distributions (NOT mandatory)
- to recognize as many songs as possible;
- to tag more songs once a time (NOT mandatory);
- to have an easy-to-use interface;
- to do the work as fast as possible;
- no crashes (if possible);

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,I've got 2GB of RAM and a 3GHz processor (dual-core),if that's useful.
Incidentally,I already tried MusicBrainz Picard,Kid3 and MP3Tag (when I used Windows) and they are pretty good at what they do...But is too much work to be done manually,in my opinion,so please answer!
Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Winamp could do that, but it doesn't run on Linux. Add the songs to the playlist, select multiple at once, right-click and send to `Auto Tag`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MusicBrainZ Picard](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) is a cross-platform, free as in freedom and free beer music tagger.  [Here](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/How_to_Tag_Files_With_Picard)  is a quick guide to efficient file tagging.

It is **free**, **cross-platform**, integrates well with most **Linux** media players, recognizes any song present in an album registered on the [**MusicBrainZ** database](https://musicbrainz.org/), which is pretty complete on most genres and easy to contribute to, tags a great many song at once if used as a stand-alone app (the plugins for third-parties vary in quality), and **couldn't be easier** to use.

Comment: Thanks!I tried it but it doesn't scan all my songs,which are almost 320...Picard stops processing after almost 40 or 50 songs (I tried it twice)!And I didn't save the songs because I don't understand something:the program only arranges the songs in albums,or it is doing all I said in my question (album cover,genre,etc.)?

Comment: http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewtopic.php?id=4399 might help you. I regularly rescan 1000+ folders without any trouble, but some users do seem to get into trouble... It does tag songs with genre, cover etc., see [this](http://ajiteshmadai.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/automatically-tag-and-add-albumart-to-your-music-files-with-musicbrainz-picard/).

Answer (score 2):

TuneUp from [TuneUpMedia.com](http://tuneupmedia.com) is by far the best solution in my opinion, although it may not be ideal in your case. I have used TuneUp to clean and tag my iTunes library for God knows how long, and I haven't been able to find anything that works nearly as well or as easily.

TuneUp had some major issues as of the past few months after a management change, but the company went bankrupt and was inherited by a few of the original developers, who re-released the old, perfect version. Everything is great again! (I add this in case you look up reviews online from the terrible version 3.0)

TuneUp works with iTunes, so you will not be able to use it on Linux. It will work on Mac or PC. Even if you don't want to use iTunes, it is definately worth it to import your music quickly into iTunes, tag it with TuneUp, then pull it back to whatever else you were using before.

TuneUp will tag songs with no metadata or filename info by analyzing the actual song with online databases, so it's great for your purpose. Additionally, it's very quick, and it finds lyrics, cover artwork, and other information as well.

It's not free but they offer a free trial that may cover you depending on the size of your library. I believe it can do up to 1,000 songs at once, so even if you have 11,000 songs in your library like me, it's not all that much work to clean everything.

Comment: Forgot to mention, TuneUp is very stable (doesn't crash), and offers lots of features for continuous use like concert tracking and song/artist information and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

[SongKong](http://www.jthink.net/songkong) is designed exactly for this, automatic song identification with the minimum of user interaction just providing enough options for most user scenarios.

It can be used on a collection of any size, and runs on Linux (as well as OSX and windows).

It is not free, but you can use the free trial to generate a html report showing exactly what every song has been matched so you can properly evaluate it. It does fulfill all your other requirements.

This [video](https://youtu.be/JzTQPaGPDrs?list=PLBEfu8eXW2xq54kLV_Gw5ZnG6igZEM6KO) shows the matching process in action

Disclaimer:I am the SongKong developer.